# creating jquery function that redirects focus to input if blank, otherwise perform normal search

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i am working on a jquery script for normal wordpress search form, where if user does not type anything in search the `focus()` goes to the input field and stops the search to happen, otherwise let the search run normally when something is typed in.

i have the following script that works for the if check and if nothing is typed in, the focus() is redirected. but my problem now is when a normal search happens, the search input button is not clicking/working. when i remove `e.preventDefault();` the search button then works, but the if check on if nothing is typed in does no work because by the time the click is checked, the page has refreshed. i have to add `e.preventDefault()` in order for my if to check and run. if i am using `e.preventDefault(`) incorrectly, or you have any insight into this issue as a whole, i would greatly appreciate it.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var $searchField = $('.search-field'),
            $searchFieldValue = $searchField.val();

        $('.search-submit').click(function(e){
            console.log($searchField);
            console.log($searchFieldValue);

            if ($searchFieldValue === '') {
                e.preventDefault();
                $searchField.get(0).focus();
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting the value **when someone clicks**, not just on initial pageload, otherwise you won't get the changed value

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.search-submit').click(function(e){
        var $searchField     = $('.search-field'),
        var searchFieldValue = $searchField.val();

        if (searchFieldValue === '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $searchField.get(0).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: right on! i didn't even notice that. this updated code works perfectly now thank you!